# Problem with EXCEL on email subscriptions with SSRS 2008

Tags: excel, reporting-services, subscription

We have a limit of 15mb for any emails from SSRS.
I have a report that was sending The email with an attached EXCEL correctly until the last few weeks. I have found that the issue is the file size is to large and it wont send.
Here is what i found if I export the report to excel and save it, it is saving at round 15.4 mb. The strange part is if i open the excel don't make any changes and just save it, the file is only around 6.9 mb.
Can anyone explain why the un-opened xls is 15.4 but the opened then saved is about half the size?

Comment: At a guess it's being created as an old format xls file, and when you save it, it's being converted to the smaller, more efficient .xlsx format

Comment: Hmm thought. but the file is still an xls format not saved as a XLSX

Comment: I was thinking that maybe it maxed the rows on each of the Sheets (there are 4 sheets on this report) then when saved it only saved the rows with data?